# How to tell MariaDB/MySQL that a column is unique due to HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, having

With `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set (which I don't want to/can't change) the following query errors with

> **ERROR 1055 (42000)**: 'dbname.test1.person_id' isn't in GROUP BY

(or equivalent longer message in mariadb).

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    thing VARCHAR(16),
    person_id INT
);

SELECT
    thing,
    person_id
FROM
    test1
GROUP BY
    thing
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) = 1
```

How can I "tell" MySQL that I know the person_id is unambiguous because of the HAVING clause? I don't want to use `ANY_VALUE` because that isn't available in all the dbs where this code needs to run.

Edit: It has been rightly pointed out that something like `MAX` will work on person_id here but the MAX value of a person_id doesn't really make sense and feels fragile to future changes. Is there a better way of structuring the query so that isn't necessay?

Comment: "isn't available in all the dbs" -- where is it missing?

Comment: In some of the dev's local dbs for sure. I'm not sure about other places. I don't want to require the requisite version of MySQL/Mariadb for the codebase to work if at all possible. I can't quite put my finger on it but I'm also not a fan of ANY_VALUE. It feels dangerous in that it does something arbitrary. Maybe I'm being squeamish about nothing but I did find a bug in a similar bit of SQL that I rewrote because ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY didn't like it. I feel like ANY_VALUE would mask similar bugs in the same way turning off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY would.

Comment: `ANY_VALUE()` _exposes_ a bug that has always been there.  It doesn't change anything other than making it obvious that the value provided is 'arbitrary'.  That's the way it has always worked, to the consternation of many a MySQL user.

Comment: Definitely. But I think I’d rather do the rewrites than continue to hide the behavior. The only annoyance is listing out all the SELECTed fields from a table where the primary key is already in the GROUP BY. That feels pretty verbose/redundant but maybe it’s not as simple as the PK being enough info for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a subquery to find all the things that are unique to one person:

```
SELECT                  
    thing      
FROM          
    test1      
GROUP BY          
    thing     
HAVING         
    COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) = 1
```

and then grab the details we actually want in the outer query now we know which things we care about:

```
SELECT 
    person_id, 
    thing 
FROM 
    test1 
WHERE 
    thing IN 
        (
            SELECT                  
                thing      
            FROM          
                test1      
            GROUP BY          
                thing     
            HAVING         
                COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) = 1
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `MAX()` aggregation for `person_id` column

```
SELECT
    thing,
    MAX(person_id) AS person_id
FROM
    test1
GROUP BY
    thing
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) = 1
```

`person_id` is already wanted to be selected distinctly, and `MAX()` works for both string or numeric values. This way, only remains one non-aggregated column which conforms for each type of DBMS, including MySQL with mode of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is set.

Comment: That will work but it feels "dangerous". Future changes to the query may invalidate the assumption that MAX is ok and give weird results. I'm probably being over-cautious but is there some way to restructure the query so that the intent is clear as well as passing the FULL_GROUP_BY check?

Comment: Have you ever thought adding person_id column to GROUP BY clause @ThomasDavidBaker . What issues might arise for your exact cases?

Comment: If I add person_id to the group by then the HAVING clause no longer finds me items unique to a single person but instead finds every "thing" for every person. Perhaps I can add person_id to the group by and use some outer query to find the unique people.

Comment: well, you're right, and I am not able construct any other types of such query in mind for your case @ThomasDavidBaker .

Comment: An alternative is `GROUP_CONCAT(person_id)`.